# invalid syntax in execution function from module in microPython

Tags: python, syntax-error, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I'm working with micropython, and learning from the documentation but I came across this error, it works running network.py, but it doesn't work running main.py
running from thonny IDE
network.py

```
import time 
import network 
import urequests


class netWireless:

    def setUp(ssid,password):

        wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
        wlan.active(True)
        wlan.connect(ssid,password)

        max_wait = 10

        while max_wait > 0:
            if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >=  3:
                break
            max_wait -= 1
            print("waiting for connection...")
            time.sleep(1)
        if wlan.status() != 3:
            raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
            return 0;
        else:
            print('connected')
            status = wlan.ifconfig()
            print('ip = ' + status[0])
            return 1;

    def getJSON(url):
            response = urequests.get(url)
            json = response.json()
            response.close()
            return json;

#working
netWireless.setUp('ssid','password')
```

main.py

```
import config
import modules.network
import modules.dateTime

#not working 
setUpStatus = netWireless.setUp('ssid','password')
```

Shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "modules/network.py", line 6
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i already tried:
pass the values to the function in variable form, assign the variable to have the return

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   How are you running this script?

Comment: @ewokx from thonny in rasp pico

Comment: You are importing ```network``` within ```network.py```?  If that ```import network``` refers to a different module,  I would suggest you rename your ```network.py``` to something else.

Answer (score -1):

You are importing network within network.py? If that import network refers to a different module, I would suggest you rename your network.py to something else. - @wokx

RENAME FILE

*the Import:

```
from modules.wirelessCon import *
```

Comment: Suggesting a wildcard import is not the best of ideas. To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports): "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).